# Can I overflow uint32_t in a temporary result?

Tags: c

Basically what happens on a 32bit system when I do this:

```
uint32_t test (void)
{
  uint32_t myInt;

  myInt = ((0xFFFFFFFF * 0xFFFFFFFF) % 256u );

  return myInt;
}
```

Comment: Can you, may you, should you? Which one are you asking?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: Or use the `inttypes.h` macros to explicitly use constants with known size, e.g.: `(UINT64_C(0xFFFFFFFF) * UINT64_C(0xFFFFFFFF)) % 256u`, which gets consistent behavior, at the cost of some verbosity.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: The `lu` is not necessary, `u` by itself is fine.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, the `l` is *not* necessary to ensure that the constants each have the specified value, and it does not ensure that the multiplication of the two constant values will not overflow.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I think John's point is that there is no guarantee that their product fits in `unsigned long`, which makes using `l` pointless. With `ull` (forcing both operands of the multiplication to be `unsigned long long`), you'd have a guarantee that the product fits.

Comment: Sure, @PatrickRoberts, but that's a big enough caveat to invalidate your assertion.  The maximum representable value of type `unsigned long` can be as small as 2^32 - 1, and that bound is extremely common in practice.  Where it applies, the `l` does nothing to prevent the OP's multiplication from overflowing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's assume that `int` is 32 bits.

1. `0xFFFFFFFF` will have type `unsigned int`. There are special rules that explain this, but because it is a hexadecimal constant and it doesn't fit in `int`, but does fit in `unsigned int`, it ends up as `unsigned int`.
2. `0xFFFFFFFF * 0xFFFFFFFF` will first go through the usual arithmetic conversions, but since both sides are `unsigned int`, nothing happens. The result of the multiplication is `0xfffffffe00000001` which is reduced to `unsigned int` by using the modulo 2<sup>32</sup> value, resulting in the value 1 with type `unsigned int`.
3. `(unsigned int)1 % 256u` is equal to `1` and has type `unsigned int`. Usual arithmetic conversions apply here too, but again, both operands are `unsigned int` so nothing happens.
4. The result is converted to `uint32_t`, but it's already `unsigned int` which has the same range.

**However,** let's instead suppose that `int` is 64 bits.

1. `0xFFFFFFFF` will have type `int`.
2. `0xFFFFFFFF * 0xFFFFFFFF` will overflow! This is undefined behavior. At this point we stop trying to figure out what the program does, because it could do anything. Maybe the compiler would decide not to emit code for this function, or something equally absurd.

This would happen in a so-called "ILP64" or "SILP64" architecture. These architectures are rare but they *do exist.* We can avoid these portability problems by using `0xFFFFFFFFu`.

Comment: This is one of the most counter-intuitive outcomes I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

Unsigned integer overflowing means you can try to put a value greater than the range of what it can hold - but it will wrap and will put a number modulo `UINT32_MAX+1`. In fact in this case also that will happen *provided you append the `U` or `u` with the integer literals*. Otherwise integer literals <strike>are considered</strike>when turns out to be signed (As you didn't specify anything), will result in overflow due to multiplication and signed integer overflow which is Undefined Behavior.

Again back to the explanation, here when you are multiplying this (ensuring that they are unsigned it (the result) will wrap in `UINT32_MAX+1` by wrapping in it is meant that if it is bigger than `uint32_t` then the result will be applied over modulous of `UINT32_MAX`) and then we apply modulo operation with `256u` and then that result is stored in `uint32_t` and returned from the method. (Note that the result of multiplication if overflows will be at first taken as modulo of `UINT_MAX+1`)

Comment: The hex literals are unsigned.

Comment: Yes, see §6.4.4.1 of n1256, for example.

Comment: Doesn't that section of the standard imply that if `int` happens to have width 64 bits on the target platform, then `0xFFFFFFFF` would be signed?

Comment: @MarkDickinson Actually you are right.. there are pretty complex rules if we read http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1p5 So yeah, better have suffix

Comment: @EugeneSh., hex constants without a `u` or `U` suffix may be either signed or unsigned -- see your own link.  It depends on the types that can represent the value.

Comment: @EugeneSh. C does not have hex literals.  It does have hex constants.  In C and C++ literals can have their address taken.

Comment: "Otherwise integer literals are considered signed" not quite.  See C11 §6.4.4.1 5.

Comment: @chux.: Ah yes literals if capable are storing in `int` they will be stored in one if not then they will be in unsigned int and so on..int, unsigned int, long, unsigned long, long long, unsigned long long..which ever comes first and capable of storing it

Comment: This answer contains a couple different errors or omissions. (1) It claims that the integer constants are signed, in fact this depends on the ranges of the relevant types. (2) It claims that the result of the multiplication is reduced modulo `UINT32_MAX+1`, but this is only coincidentally true under certain circumstances. The `uint32_t` type is only relevant at the end.

Comment: @DietrichEpp.: (1) Edited before your comment admit that statement was there. (2) second point I dont understand...unsigned int arithmetic wraps on the `max value it can hold +1` ... Instead of explaining like you did I just mentioned that unless `U` is mentioned there is a scope of it being signed also which may lead to UB...(on overflow). using `U` we avoid that UB case completely.

Comment: (1) I suppose the answer does say that, but it is confusing. (2) The max value that an `unsigned int` can hold is `UINT_MAX`, not `UINT32_MAX`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp.: (2) True yep...so when we are putting that value in `uint32_t` what will happen? It would wrap?? isn't it? (That wrapping would be not in `UINT_MAX`)...`uint32_t` can hold  upto`UINT32_MAX`..I am going wrong somewhere?

Comment: When you put it in `uint32_t` it will wrap mod `UINT32_MAX+1`.  This only applies to the final result, though. This does not apply to the multiplication.

Comment: @DietrichEpp.: Ah yes...why would the container affect from before hand...and the result of multiplication will be first `UINT_MAX+1` and then `UINT32_MAX+1`...I didn't mention it explicitly. which i should and now did.